# angular.js using ng-options to only display unique values

Tags: angularjs

If I have an array

```
$scope.colors = [
{name:'black', shade:'dark'},
{name:'white', shade:'light'},
{name:'red', shade:'dark'},
{name:'red', shade:'dark'},
{name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
```

];

Is it possible to use ng-options to build a select element with only unique values in the dropdown, so red will only display once?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) has exactly what you need, the ´unique´ filter ([src code](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)).

Example:

```
ng-options="color in colors | unique:'name'"
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use uniq/unique filter of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.
**Usage:** `collection | unique: 'property'`  or `collection | unique: 'nested.property'`

**JS:**

```
$scope.colors = [
 {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
 {name:'white', shade:'light'},
 {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
 {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
 {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-options="color in colors | unique:'name'"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find that the above replies worked. I did the following:

Implemented my `ng-options` this way:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="cand.candidate for cand in candidates  | unique:'candidate'">
   <option value="">Select Candidate</option>
</select>
```

Add your module to your app:

```
var app = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ui.unique']);
```

Install just Ui Utils Unique, using Bower. [Link to instructions.](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

Answer (score -4):

```
src="js/vendor/bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js"> 
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
ng-repeat="color in colors | unique:'name'">{{color.name}}
```