# ngRepeat:dupes even with track by $index (special case)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

Brief background:- Am building a social networking site and am storing the statuses and users with MongoDB. So u have a status like this for example

```
{
    "status" : "Hello world.",
    "profileURL" : "ac271a307",
    "comments" : [ ],
    "time" : "2013-10-28T22:25:24.278Z",
    "active" : true,
    "owner" : DBRef("users", "abc@efg.com"), // MongoDB Reference to the users Collection
    "_id" : ObjectId("526ee454da46f33bf8000002")
}
```

Now on angular am doing;

```
<li ng-repeat="status in statuses | isUserStatus track by status['_id']" ng-show="status.active" class="user-status-bland">

    // In here i display the users data and the status itself.
</li>
```

## Note: All this works perfect

But here's is problem. Am using Websockets to automatically update and add the new statuses to $rootScope.statuses.

```
socket.on('new status', function(status) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            // stack the new status at the top of all statuses.
            $rootScope.statuses.unshift(status);
        });
    }, 0);
})
```

Now if you do a console.log() of 'status' inside the websocket callback, i get the status and it appears twice. In a sense that the websocket was sent twice (of which i have no control over). So when this is put inside "$rootScope.statuses" thats when i get the error **"Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys."** It don't make sense because I am actually using $track by status['_id']

Comment: Have you seen this question yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748440/angular-js-using-ng-options-to-only-display-unique-values 
Basically you can download a plugin that will do all of the work of getting the unique items in your data..

Comment: Thanks @BuddhistBeast. Your comment lead me to the right path man. The credit goes to you.

Comment: For sure! I literally hit a dead end when I first tried doing the exact same thing... It took me a few hours to finally realize that a plugin was going to resolve everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BuddistBeast comment (underneath my question) lead me in the right path to fixing my problem. I ended up adding https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter plugin and using its "unique" filter provided therein. That fixed the ngRepeat dupes errors showing up. But then, I'd still see duplicated statuses appearing for some reason (but no error on the console). So if i post "hi" for example, i would see "hi" appearing twice. I did manage to fix it altogether, but the fix to that problem is separate and beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<li ng-repeat="status in statuses track by $index | isUserStatus " ng-show="status.active" class="user-status-bland">
```

or:

```
<li ng-repeat="status in statuses | isUserStatus track by $index" ng-show="status.active" class="user-status-bland">
```

Comment: I've tried that already and when i post a status, i **dont't** get an error at all, but some weird stuff happen. I now have duplicated statuses. So for example lets say i post the status "hi", it would appear like 5 times (duplicated) on the UI...

When i use the previous track by status['_id'], i don't get the duplicates but i get the error.

Comment: For now, try removing `| isUserStatus` part and see what happens - and make sure you keep `track by $index` all the times, that's the way to use it

Comment: I think this `$index` itself doesn't have anything to do with the ID of your application's implementation. `track by $index` is used just to make sure that your `ngRepeat`ed values are always going to be unique (because array keys will be unique - 0,1,2,3,....)

Comment: The way i understand the use of track by $index is that, ($index) is just the position of the key. E.g. if you have an array ["a","b","c"]; $index would be the positions of the elements. So "a" is 0, b is 1 and etc. But if u have an object, of { a: "a", b: "b" }, inside angular, it would do something similar to the previous. So essential you **don't** have to say track by $index, you can say track by any key **that is unique**. But in answer to your suggestion (of which i greatly appreciate since your trying to help me using your valuable time), i did try what you suggested and it didn't work.

Comment: I noticed you're using `$timeout` with `0` set for timeout time, why is that?
Can you learn more by following the error link seen in the browser console?

Comment: well, $timeout is used to just prevent hitting the digest cycle. if i do $rootScope.$apply() which updates my new changes to the UI.
I too thought that would be the case, i tried to remove all that but it still says the same thing. It's pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try to track by `$id(status)` it might solve your issue