# How to make ng-options for display only the different value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I want to make my `ng-options` element to display only the different value.
So now i have this.

[image: Example image]

But I want it to display only one by one value.
Example:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="main.singleProductListSelected">
    <option value="test_pizza">Pizza Favorites</option>
    <option value="test_pizza">Pasta</option>
    <option value="test_pizza">Salads</option>
</select>
```

This is my html code

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="main.singleProductListSelected"
        ng-options="singleOrdersProduct.category.name 
                    for singleOrdersProduct in main.singleOrdersProductOptions">
</select>
```

Can I do this or i have to change the variable result?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best way is to eliminate all the duplicates in that array through business logic (through javascript).

Answer (score 0):

`<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="main.singleProductListSelected"
        ng-options="singleOrdersProduct.category.name for singleOrdersProduct in main.singleOrdersProductOptions | unique:'singleOrdersProduct.category.name'">
</select>`

add unique: 'your item name here'

Comment: Refer this link it is answered here, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748440/angular-js-using-ng-options-to-only-display-unique-values). You should add and inject the unique filter in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend lodash like library and create a array of unique value to use inside ng-options

inside controller

```
uniqueNames = _.uniq(_.pluck(main.singleOrdersProductOptions, 'name'))
```

use this uniqueNames inside select ng-options. Performance wise this would be good option