# Unique ng-options in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to get unique results in angular ng-options on a select box.

```
<select ng-model="nationality" id="nationality" 
        ng-options="player as player.nationality for player in players></select>
```

The above code will get me all the nationality's however it show's duplicates.

```
<select ng-model="nationality" id="nationality" 
        ng-options="player as players | unique: 'player.nationality'"></select>
```

When I try this code angular throw's errors and shows me nothing in the select box.

*Controller*

```
var app = angular.module('premierLeagueDB', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "api.php/clubs",
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.clubs = response.data.club;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.showError = response.statusText;
});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the controller

Comment: seems like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748440/angular-js-using-ng-options-to-only-display-unique-values

Comment: There's no such thing called `unique` in angular if you're not getting it from a 3rd party library. Why don't you filter out duplicates in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code will work for you :

```
<select ng-model="nationality" id="nationality" ng-options="player as players | unique: 'nationality' "></select>
```

===EDIT===

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results) , you need the third-party library to provide you the `filter` service, include [this library](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) in your html file.

==EDIT 2===
In order to demo how this works I make a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yufeng/w1LLhpxd/). In this fiddle I use `anuglar-ui` library to replace the module and it works as expected.

In case that you only need 'ui.filters' module but not the other parts(import only necessary modules is the best practice), here is [another fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yufeng/wsj0fykL/) that only imports the `unique` function from the `ui-filter` module.

Comment: This gives me an error.

```angular.js:12416Error: [ngOptions:iexp]```

Comment: I have included the third party library you said about. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @GarethFrazer please try the fiddle link I posted in the answer, I think it will work for you

Comment: @david_Tao When I add ```['ui.filters']``` it breaks everything

Comment: sorry I forget to mention about one thing there: if you just want to load that single 'filter' function,  you need to modify the declaration of 3rd party code from `angular.module('ui.filters').filter('unique', function () {...});` to `angular.module('ui.filters', []).filter('unique', function () {...});` because the former one already assume you have loaded module the 'ui.filters' but actually you don't. So add an empty '[]' as the second parameter to initialize the 'ui.filter' module.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you for you're time and help!